# Using a non-standard font in html

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am trying to get a non-standard font working on my website. It's not working, but I don't know why.

The relevant HTML:

```html
<div class="links">
  This should be written in the font, but isn't.
</div>
```

The relevant CSS:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Woodbonnet';
    src: url('/home/kco/WoodBonnet-GrotesqueNo4.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
         url('/home/kco/WoodBonnet-GrotesqueNo4.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('/home/kco/WoodBonnet-GrotesqueNo4.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
         url('/home/kco/WoodBonnet-GrotesqueNo4.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
         url('/home/kco/WoodBonnet-GrotesqueNo4.otf')  format('opentype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('/home/kco/WoodBonnet-GrotesqueNo4.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/home/kco/WoodBonnet-GrotesqueNo4.svg') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}

.links{
    font-family: 'Woodbonnet', Fallback, sans-serif;
    background-color: #034124;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 35px;
    /* padding-left: 20px */
    /* text-align: right; */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The font files are all in the same folder as the html file.

Comment: but where is the CSS file? you should also consider the CSS file

Comment: The css file is also in the same folder. The css file is working for other things, so it is in the right location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a path problem. Then HTML file and Font files must be in the same directory. Then try with inline style in HTML first and add some little changes. I think the additional `src:` after the `;` is a must:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Font Test</title>
    <style>
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Woodbonnet';
    src:url('./WoodBonnet-GrotesqueNo4.eot?#iefix');
    src:url('./WoodBonnet-GrotesqueNo4.eot?#iefix') format('eot'),
        url('./WoodBonnet-GrotesqueNo4.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('./WoodBonnet-GrotesqueNo4.woff') format('woff'),
        url('./WoodBonnet-GrotesqueNo4.otf') format('opentype'),
        url('./WoodBonnet-GrotesqueNo4.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('./WoodBonnet-GrotesqueNo4.svg#Woodbonnet') format('svg');
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="links">This should be written in the font, but isn't.</div>
  </body>
</html>
```